# Method that Returns All Products for a particular category ASP.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Need some help. I have 2 tables

Product Type:- 
ID,
Name

Product :-
ID,
ProductTypeID (FK from Product Type table),
Price,
Name

I want to write a method which returns List of all products for the selected Product Type this is in ASP.net

Below is what I wrote so far but don't know what to write here ...List products =???

```
public List<Product> GetAllProductsByCategory()
    {

            using (GarageEntities db = new GarageEntities()) 
            {
                List<Product> products =  ?????
                return products;
            }  

    }
```

If there is any other simple method please let me know.

Thanks In advance

Comment: `db.Products.Where(...)` would probably be a good start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

```
public List<Product> GetAllProductsByCategory(int ProductTypeId)
    {
            using (GarageEntities db = new GarageEntities()) 
            {
                List<Product> products = db.Products.where(x=>x.ProductTypeID==ProductTypeId).toList()
                return products;
            }  

    }
```

Comment: It works thank you so much.Can you please explain what this means :- x=>

Comment: `x=>` this means it makes alias of Products. and please make my answer right